# TypeError: locals must be a mapping

Tags: python, math

In Python 3.4.3 I have this code.

```
operator = random.choice('-+')  
    numTheF = random.choice(numsUseF)  
    numTheS = random.choice(numsUseS)   
    print ('What is', int(numTheF), operator, int(numTheS))  
    ansReal = eval(int(numTheF), operator, int(numTheS))  
    ansUser = input ('?')  
    if ansUser == ansReal:    
        score += 1  
        question += 1
```

All the variables are properly set up but I can't get the `ansReal` to output the actual answer.

Here is the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Programming Princ\Task One.py", line 34, in       <module>
ansReal = eval(int(numTheF), operator, int(numTheS))
TypeError: locals must be a mapping
```

Comment: I don't condone the use of `eval` at all, but... You should pass only one argument to `eval` here. You are passing three. (hint: use string concatenation)

Answer (score 1):

`eval()` takes three arguments, the latter two of which are optional. The first is the expression (as a `str`ing) to evaluate; the latter two, if present, must be mappings that will be used for the global and local namespaces in which to evaluate the expression. See [the documentation on `eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) for more information.

As [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567183/typeerror-locals-must-be-a-mapping/29567268#comment47283919_29567183), I do not condone the use of `eval()`. You're already using `int()` to parse strings into integers; that's a good start—consider also simply adding or subtracting those integers to get the real answer.